# how to declare olFormatHtml in vb

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am trying to send mail that is formated as HTML but I get an error showing that `olFormatHtml` is not declared. How do I declare it?

Comment: Got the error out. Just replaced `olFormatHtml` with `Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML`. So nice to answer myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `olFormatHtml` with `Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VBA in Excel 2007 to attach a workbook to an email and format the body of that email.  I just tried this suggestion and got a run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Instead I set `.bodyformat = 2` to display email text as html, and it worked.  For example....

```
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailItem1 = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

With MailItem1
    .BodyFormat = 2
    'sample formatting change....
    .htmlbody = "<font color = 'red'>" & "SAMPLE TEXT" & "</font><br/>"
    .display
End With

Set MailItem1 = Nothing
Set Outlook = Nothing
```